# How to retrieve distinct records using Sql server while the table continues to build?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I`m putting together a table with columns (F_name, L_name, Address, City, State, Zip and Phone #). While it continues to pull from the database, I want to run a query to pull records with distinct phone #s only.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Dennis.

Comment: I am not sure what you question is.  What do you mean by the table building?  It sounds like you want to pull data from a table that another query is inserting data into. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, Adam?

Comment: What do you mean by "records with distinct phone numbers only"?  Do you mean that you want to get a list of just the phone numbers?  Or that records that have the same phone number as a previously-retrieved record should not be returned?

Answer (score 0):

Great!  I just wanted to make sure I understood the question.  To get a distinct list of phone numbers, you just have to run a query like this

```
select distinct phonenbr from MyTableBeingLoaded
```

If you find your query is taking a long time it could be getting blocked. in which case you can use something like this to get a result (note this should not be used in production code, as nolock can cause weird results.

```
select distinct phonenbr from MyTableBeingLoaded with(nolock)
```

Comment: Like to clarify some more... I am selecting a file with several thousand records from a database . As i am doing the extract of 20 different fields, I want to make sure that the file i selected does not have duplicate phones